# Ansible can't git clone from enterprise git server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, git, ansible, ssh-keys

Hi I have enterprise git server where I created a private `test-repo` and added a ssh-key on the deploy ssh key form. I defined a `git` role in my common roles which is having below yml definition.

```
---

- name: github enterprise private key
  copy: >
    src=id_rsa_ghe
    dest=/etc/id_rsa_ghe
    owner=root
    group=root
    mode=0600

- name: clone test-repo project
  git:
    repo: git@git.example-private.com:code/test-repo.git
    dest: /etc/test-repo
    accept_hostkey: true
    key_file: /etc/id_rsa_ghe
```

in `roles/common/git` I defined `files` folder where I put my private key for git clone however I am still getting error as below

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/git", "fetch", "--tags", "origin"], "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  ERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"}

Below are my system details. And I am running this playbook locally on one of my server.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ansible --version
ansible 2.2.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Below is the actual error which I get repository not found.

> Using module file
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/core/source_control/git.py
>   <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root <127.0.0.1> EXEC
>   /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "`echo
>   ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507`" && echo
>   ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507="`echo
>   ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507`" ) && sleep
>   0' <127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmp2Bijvu TO
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507/git.py
>   <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507/
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507/git.py
>   && sleep 0' <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507/git.py;
>   rm -rf
>   "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487398723.48-100968102221507/"
>
> > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0' fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
> >         "changed": false, 
> >         "cmd": [
> >             "/usr/bin/git", 
> >             "fetch", 
> >             "--tags", 
> >             "origin"
> >         ], 
> >         "failed": true, 
> >         "invocation": {
> >             "module_args": {
> >                 "accept_hostkey": true, 
> >                 "bare": false, 
> >                 "clone": true, 
> >                 "depth": null, 
> >                 "dest": "/etc/dotfiles", 
> >                 "executable": null, 
> >                 "force": false, 
> >                 "key_file": "/etc/id_rsa_ghe", 
> >                 "recursive": true, 
> >                 "reference": null, 
> >                 "refspec": null, 
> >                 "remote": "origin", 
> >                 "repo": "git@git.example-private.com:code/test-repo.git", 
> >                 "ssh_opts": null, 
> >                 "track_submodules": false, 
> >                 "umask": null, 
> >                 "update": true, 
> >                 "verify_commit": false, 
> >                 "version": "HEAD"
> >             }, 
> >             "module_name": "git"
> >         }, 
> >         "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  ERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: Could not read from remote
> >     repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
> >     rights\nand the repository exists.\n" }

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, but you provide no information related to it. Can you clone the repository using `git`? How do you do it?

Comment: run your playbook with `-vvv`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `clone test-repo project` task has an syntax error and that is why Ansible can't find the repository. Replace the `:` with `/` for the `repo` parameter like this:

```
- name: clone test-repo project
  git:
    repo: git@git.example-private.com/code/test-repo.git
    dest: /etc/test-repo
    accept_hostkey: true
    key_file: /etc/id_rsa_ghe
```

You would use `:` to define a non standard port.

Comment: Error is still there only difference is now it says `fatal: 'git@git.example-private.com/code/test-repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: First guess: remove the `.git`. Can you checkout the repo on cmd with: `git clone git@git.example-private.com/code/test-repo.git`? Otherwise read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server#_git_on_the_server